# How to render embedded tweet widget on the server using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, oembed

My goal is to fetch the HTML & CSS for a tweet widget (like the one below) on the server.

[image: Twitter widget]

Calling Twitter's [OEmbed endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed) only returns the bare HTML for this tweet:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" width="500">
<p> Twitter users love tweeting emoji from their phones – now you can view these emoji on web! <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/emojiparty?src=hash">#emojiparty</a>          ✨</p>&mdash; Twitter Support (@Support) <a href="https://twitter.com/Support/status/451399393850052610">April 2, 2014</a>
</blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Twitter's [widget.js](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript) seems to only work on the client side. Is it possible to retrieve the full HTML & CSS for an embedded tweet on the server using node.js?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann Sorry – I've added some more information, does that clear things up?